# Partially populate a column using dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pretty straightforward problem, but I don't seem to recall how to achieve what I'm lookin for. I have a DataFrame with a string index, like this:

```
        value
 'a'      1
 'b'      2
 'c'      3
```

And also I've got a dictionary that goes like this:

```
dic={'a':3,'c':6}
```

I wanted to create a new column `value2` using the dictionary so my final DataFrame would look like this:

```
        value    value2
 'a'      1        3
 'b'      2       nan
 'c'      3        6
```

I thought it would be as straightforward as inputting `df['value2'] = dic`, but because the length of the dictionary is different than the length of the column, there's a mismatch.

So, what would be the appropiate way to populate my column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df['value2'] = df.index.map(dic)
```

---

```
   value  value2
a      1     3.0
b      2     NaN
c      3     6.0
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! In the end I managed to do it creating an empty column and then using `fillna()` but didn't seem very straightforward, so this is way better

Comment: I see, yes this might be more elegant :) @JuanC

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the value dict so you can using `assign`

```
df.assign(v2=pd.Series(dic))
Out[773]: 
   value   v2
a      1  3.0
b      2  NaN
c      3  6.0
```

Also keep in mind , `index` is the hidden key for assignment

```
df['value2'] = pd.Series(dic)
```